# How to group the data by id and find the difference of adjacent data?

Tags: python, pandas, math, dataframe

I have the following data

```
id    starting_point      ending_point
A        2525                 6565
B        5656                 8989
A        1234                 5656
A        4562                 6245
B        6496                 9999
B        1122                 2211
```

For the above data :

```
df['id'] = ['A','B','A','A','B', 'B']
df['starting_point'] =['2525','5656','1234','4562','6496','1122']
df['ending_point'] = ['6565','8989','5656','6245','9999','9999']
```

I would like to write a python code group them by their id (ie, A,B,...) and find the difference between  sum of first and second ending point of A and sum of second and third ending point of A. In this case  [(6565+5656) - (5656+6245)].

Comment: Have you tried to write actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function where select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html)  and get difference of sums:

```
df = df.groupby('id')['ending_point'] \
       .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:2].sum() - x.iloc[1:4].sum()).reset_index()
print (df)
  id  ending_point
0  A           320
1  B          6778
```

Comment: Thank you ! ís it also possible to find it using the column name ??

Comment: I am not sure if understand, do you need `df = df.groupby('id')['starting_point', 'ending_point'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:2].sum() - x.iloc[1:4].sum()).reset_index()` ?

Comment: sorry! that was a mistake ! thank you so much ! it works !

Comment: No problem, nice day!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can scip the second ending point, as `(6565+5656) - (5656+6245)` == `6565 - 6245`:

```
In [15]: df.groupby('id')['ending_point'].apply(lambda x: x - x.shift(-2))
Out[15]:
0     320.0
1    6778.0
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
5       NaN
Name: ending_point, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
group = df.groupby('id')
group['ending_point'].first() - group['ending_point'].last()
```